# Combinatorics using a geometric diagram

Tags: probability, combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, contest-math, combinations

[image]

How can I do this without trial-and-error?

It has something to do with a triangle and summing the next row?

Comment: I assume that in each step you have to move a given row to the row below it?  There are multiple ways to interpret what a path is, as written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After seeing JorleArbake's comment linking to http://abelkonkurransen.no/problems/abel_1314_r1_sol_nb.pdf it includes a solution described here:

[image: Norwegian solution]

Their argument is to recursively find the number of paths from the starting cell by finding the number of paths starting from cells in the middle of the grid instead.

For all of the triangles on the bottom row, there is only one path starting from it and leading to the end (namely it itself).  From there, notice that picking a starting square on the next level up, you may continue downwards to any of the adjacent cells, thus inheriting all of their (possibly multiple) different paths having started from each of them.  Continuing this process working upwards, you find that you can find the total number of paths from some parent cell is equal to the sum of the total number of paths from each adjacent child.  Filling in the grid from bottom up leads eventually to $56+41+56 = 153$

---

-Edit- Below is my original answer to this question, which still has some merit in leaving up since it shows a method to at least bound the size on the answer using elementary arguments.

In a very common question similar to this one, the definition of "adjacent" would have been such that at every step we have only three moves possible (straight down, down-left, or down-right), in which case the answer would be $3^4=81$ seen quickly from the multiplication principle.

With the definition of "adjacency" given here as two cells are adjacent if their respective borders share at least one point in common (i.e., share a corner vertex or edge), you can quickly see that there will be *at least 3* choices available at every step (and in particular at some steps will have 4 or even 5 choices available), and that the available paths from the previously mentioned problem will all be valid paths for this one.  As such we know that the answer will be strictly greater than 81.  This rules out the possibility of $(a)$ as being the correct answer.

Notice then also that there will be *at most 5* choices available at each step, so the number of possibilities must be strictly less than $5^4=625$, thus ruling out the possibility of $(e)$ being the answer.

To proceed further, intuitively one might expect that instead of looking at $3^4$ and $5^4$, you could look at the average number of choices raised to the fourth power (through some argument relating to geometric mean).  The number of choices from each triangle in order is: 3,4,3,4,4,3,5,3,4,4,3,5,3,5,3,4.  So, the average seems slightly under 4.  Thus we would expect the total number of possibilities to be less than $4^4 = 256$, ruling out $(d)$ as being a correct answer.

This leaves us with two possibilities left, either $(b)$ or $(c)$.  I do not see at the moment a good argument to choose between these two.

Comment: I saw the solution, apparently its like pascals triangle, http://abelkonkurransen.no/problems/abel_1314_r1_sol_nb.pdf "oppgave 15". But I still dont understandtheir method.

Comment: I may have made a mistake but I cannot see it. Unlike to official Norwegian solution, I started at the top and worked down to get $1, 3, 11, 41, 163$ which starts the same as  [OEIS A151086](http://oeis.org/A151086), a sequence related to restricted lattice walks. My $41 = 1+7+7+11+7+7+1$

Comment: @JorleArbake the solution in the link you provided does agree with my program for the next term in the sequence of 571. I will edit my answer one final time with my understanding of their solution (which is quite nice, I might not have thought of it that way without seeing it).

Comment: @JMoravitz, still, what is this method/rule?

Comment: @JorleArbake Recursively fill in numbers into each cell equal to the number of paths starting from the cell to the bottom row.  Start filling it in by setting all numbers on the bottom row equal to 1, and from there recursively fill in the rest of the triangles from bottom up by noting that any parent cell will inherit all possible paths from each adjacent child cell.  I.e., to get the number for a triangle in question add all numbers from all triangles in the row below that are adjacent to the triangle in question.  Ex. 19=3+5+3+5+3 and 11=3+5+3.

Comment: But why does adding up give how many adjecenies there are?

Answer (score 0):

Simple enumeration works well for this question because the number of rows is small:
$$ \begin{array}{ccccccccc}&&&& 0 &&&& \\ \hline &&&& 1 &&&& \\ &&& 1 && 1 &&& \\ \hline &&& 3 && 3 &&& \\ && 1 && 3 && 1 && \\ \hline && 7 && 11 && 7 && \\ & 1 && 7 && 7 && 1 & \\ \hline & 15 && 33 && 33 && 15 & \\ 1 && 15 && 25 && 15 && 1 \end{array}$$
The rule to find the value in a triangle is to add up all the values of the triangles in the previous row that are incident by a vertex or edge.  In the above diagram, rows are separated by lines.  It is not difficult to do this calculation, but if there are many such rows, it rapidly becomes tedious and a general formula is desirable.  But for a contest problem, I think direct enumeration is the fastest and most efficient solution, and it probably isn't expected that one should find a general formula.  But we can see an addition pattern here:  in the upper half-rows, each number is the sum of the **five** numbers above it in the previous whole row:  so for example, $33 = 1 + 7 + 7 + 11 + 7$.  For the lower half-rows, each number is the sum of the **three** numbers above it in the previous whole row:  so for example, $$25 = 7 + 11 + 7.$$  Given this pattern, one could probably derive something more general, but I am not inclined to do this at this time.

Answer (score -1):

Just want to point out that the average number of choices is $3.75$, so the answer must be lower than $197.75$. The answer must be b) $153$ (from choices provided).